# Nand2Tetris Weird screen behavior

Tags: nand2tetris

I'm currently taking the nand2tetris course and one assignement was to set the screen color to black when a key is pressed. That's my code, which passes the test script but the screen look like that, which according to other posts on nand2tetris does not look like the normal behavior. [image: screenshot]. Any ideas why?

```
(BEGIN)
    @KBD
    D=M
    @WHITE // go to white if no key is pressed
    D;JEQ
    
    @color
    M=-1
    @WHITEEND
    0;JMP
    
    (WHITE)
        @color
        M=0
    (WHITEEND)
    
    @SCREEN
    D=A
    @n
    M=D
    (LOOP)
        @color
        D=M
        @n
        A=M
        M=D
        
        @n
        M=M+1
        D=M
        
        @KBD
        D=D-A // When n reaches KBD, we reached the end of the screen
        @LOOP
        D;JNE
        

    @BEGIN // restart code
    0;JMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to run correctly on my Mac running the v2.5 tools. You may have a problem with your Nand2Tetris and/or Java installation or some weird display interaction that is causing the pixels to be displayed with a white border around them.

"Have you tried turning it off and turning it on again?" :)

Comment: What do you mean by "turning it off"? Turn the CPUEmulator off? I've already tried that

Comment: No, the entire computer; reboot it. The quote is a reference to the TV show, "The IT Crowd", in which one of the main characters always answers the phone "Hello, Tech Support. Have you tried turning it off and turning it on again?"

Sometimes resetting things to a (hopefully) known initial state fixes weird problems.

Comment: No, I've already tried that

Comment: But I found the problem, a resolution of 1920px makes the CPU emulator bug

Comment: Annoying, but apart of recoding the CPU emulator myself, there's not much I can do

Comment: If you can provide an exact set of steps/conditions that can repeat the problem, you should edit your post to include those details -- it's not clear what you mean by a resolution of 1920px -- do you mean the monitor resolution, or the resolution of the window? Are you running on Mac or Windows, did you zoom the emulator to full-screen, etc? And what was the work-around?

I can make sure that the developers know about the issue so hopefully it can be addressed in a future release.

Comment: To answer all your questions, I'm on windows, the editor was not in fullscreen mode. When I'm with screen resolution of 1760x990 everything works fine but when I switch to 1920x1080 or 1920x1200 the bug starts to happen.

Comment: Thank you. I have passed this on to Professor Schocken. Also,this question and your details will help out the next person who encounters this issue.

Comment: UPDATE: Seems to be the "Custom Scaling" parameter that provoked the bug.

Comment: And when I changed the resolution the custom scaling also changed